# Rails deep nested forms link_to_add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a model where you can add many questions(perguntas) to an Oportunidade form, you can then opt to add as many options(alternativas) as needed per question to be used as possible answers in radio button/checkbox forms, here's the form views:

**_perguntas.html.erb**

```
<div id="perguntas">
 <%= f.fields_for :perguntas do |m| %>
      <div class="field">
      <% tipo = m.object.tipo_pergunta.blank? ? 'Resposta aberta' : m.object.tipo_pergunta     %>
      <%= m.input :tipo_pergunta, as: :radio_buttons, label: "Tipo de Pergunta" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field plus-field">
    <%= m.input :pergunta , :label=> false , :placeholder => "Escreva uma pergunta" %>
  </div>
  <%= m.link_to_remove "-",:class => "link-add-field" %>
  <div class="field alternativa-field">
    <%= field_alternativa(m, entidade) %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="adiciona-botao-field ">
  <div class="field plus-field">
      <%= f.link_to_add "+", :perguntas, :class => "link-add-field", 'data-target' => '#perguntas' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_alternativas.html.erb**

```
   <div class="field alternativa-field">
    <div id="alternativas">
      <%= m.fields_for :alternativas do |a| %>
        <%= a.input :resposta, :placeholder => 'Alternativa', label: false %>
        <%= a.link_to_remove "-",:class => "link-add-field" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="adiciona-botao-field ">
      <div class="field plus-field">
          <%= m.link_to_add "+", :alternativas, :class => "link-add-field", 'data-target' => '#alternativas'%>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**oportunidades_controller.rb**

```
 def new
    @oportunidade = Oportunidade.new
    perguntas = @oportunidade.perguntas.build
    perguntas.alternativas.build
```

The problem happens when I try to add an option when having many questions, by clicking the alternativa object link_to_add at a second instance of Pergunta it adds an Alternativa text_field to the first Pergunta object, thus making it impossible to add Alternativas to many  specific Perguntas in a nested form, is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's look like `nested_form` gem is not supported anymore (as another Ryan Bates gems). Here is [opened pull request with fix that solves your problem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/pull/238).

As alternative I suggest you another gem for handling nested forms, [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you, I used nested form for rails 2.3 and I had those errors

Comment: Just finished converting all nested_forms to using Cocoon, it seems to be working fine, thank you!